# Converting multiple date formats into one format python

Tags: python, date, parsing

The date variable in my data is in multiple formats like 
DD/MM/YYYY
D/MM/YY
DD/M/YYYY
12/8/2017
27/08/17
8/9/2017
10/9/2017
15/09/17..

I need to change these multiple formats into one single format like DD/MM/YYYY

Tried to create a parsing function

```
def parse_date(date):
if date == '':
    return None
else:
    return dt.strptime(date, '%d/%m/%y').date()
```

and when I apply this function to my dataset, it throws me the following error..

"ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
----> 1 data.Date = data.Date.apply(parse_date)

[Unconverted Data Remains Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RiAT3.png)
ValueError: unconverted data remains: 17"

How can I solve the unconverted data remains error?

Comment: What is the date that causes that error? It could be the `%y` doesn't like the 2 digit year.

Comment: I would split the string on the slashes, and construct another string with the correct number of digits.

Comment: When I changed %y to %Y, 

I get the following error :
ValueError: time data '13/08/17' does not match format '%d/%m/%Y'

Comment: @AndyG there are around 10000 records with dates ranging from 01/01/2000 - 12/01/2018 in multiple date formats..

Comment: 10,000 isn't such a huge number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the **[dateutil module](http://labix.org/python-dateutil)** to do this

```
import dateutil.parser as dparser
a = ["12/8/2017", "27/08/17", "8/9/2017", "10/9/2017", "15/09/17"]

for i in a:
    print dparser.parse(i,fuzzy=True).date()
```

**Result:**

```
2017-12-08
2017-08-27
2017-08-09
2017-10-09
2017-09-15
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because `%y` expects a 4 digit number.

In order to cover multiple date formats, you can have a look at the `dateparser` library. ([Docs](http://dateparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/))

Otherwise you will have to manually go through possible types or extend the dates yourself. If you are sure you only need to extend the year part you can do something like this before feeding the string to the parser:

```
date_parts = date.split('/')
if len(date_parts[2]) == 2:
    date_parts[2] = "20" + date_parts[2]
date = '/'.join(date_parts)
```

I think using the `dateparser` library is the way to go, as it is more extendible.

Comment: when I tried for the entire date values from the dataset, it shows an error.

**'Series' object has no attribute 'split'**

Comment: I tried as

`date= Data.Date.Split('/')`

where Data is my actual dataset..

Comment: You are getting this error because your Date is not a string as implied in the question but a series object. You will need to iterate over the Series and apply this element-wise.

Answer (score 0):

A basic approach is to split the strings on the slashes, and then re-join them with the correct number of digits. A simple approach:

```
date = "12/8/2017"

parts = date.split("/")

print(parts) # ['12', '8', '2017']

if len(parts[0]) == 1:
    parts[0] = "0" + parts[0]
if len(parts[1]) == 1:
    parts[1] = "0" + parts[1]
if len(parts[2]) == 2:
    parts[2] = "20" + parts[2]
newDate = "/".join(parts)
# or 
newDate = parts[0] + "/" + parts[1] + "/" + parts[2]

print(newDate) # 12/08/2017
```

Then you have a consistent date format throughout. (An additional check is required if your dates extend into the last century.)

I would test this first, and consider the other answers' approaches if this is not performant.

Comment: This works perfectly for a single value. But when I tried for a series of date values from the dataset, it shows an error when I add entire dates records.. will work on it and will update! Thanks